# C# Printing a list from another class

Tags: c#, list, class

I am new to C# and I am trying to print a list that has been created in another class. The list consists of values from an enumerator along with integers and strings.

Here is the code for the list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Risk
{
    public class RiskService
    {
        private readonly Resource _matt = new Resource { Id = 1, Name = "Matt Sharpe" };
        private readonly Resource _john = new Resource { Id = 2, Name = "John Hillhouse" };
        private readonly Resource _julian = new Resource { Id = 3, Name = "Julian Jelfs" };
        private readonly Resource _darren = new Resource { Id = 4, Name = "Darren Thorpe" };
        private readonly Resource _jonm = new Resource { Id = 5, Name = "Jon Moore" };

        public List<Risk> GetRisks()
        {
            var risks = new List<Risk>();
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 1, Owner = _matt, RiskScore = 5, Status = RiskStatus.Approved, Title = "Lack Build Capacity In Dockyard" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 2, Owner = _john, RiskScore = 10, Status = RiskStatus.Unapproved, Title = "Small scale fire in warehouse" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 3, Owner = _matt, RiskScore = 17, Status = RiskStatus.Mitigated, Title = "Contract delays" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 4, Owner = _julian, RiskScore = 23, Status = RiskStatus.Open, Title = "Supplier insolvency" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 5, Owner = _darren, RiskScore = 13, Status = RiskStatus.Closed, Title = "Loss of key staff" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 6, Owner = _jonm, RiskScore = 97, Status = RiskStatus.Open, Title = "Fire in plant" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 7, Owner = _jonm, RiskScore = 97, Status = RiskStatus.Open, Title = "Fire in backup plant" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 8, Owner = _jonm, RiskScore = 45, Status = RiskStatus.Unapproved, Title = "Disaster recovery doesn't cover fire" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 9, Owner = _darren, RiskScore = 36, Status = RiskStatus.Approved, Title = "Component fails to meet performance" });
            risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 10, Owner = _john, RiskScore = 36, Status = RiskStatus.Approved, Title = "Component fails to meet performance" });
            return risks;
        }
    }

    public class Risk
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Resource Owner { get; set; }
        public RiskStatus Status { get; set; }
        public int RiskScore { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public enum RiskStatus
    {
        Unapproved,
        Approved,
        Open,
        Closed,
        Mitigated
    }
}
```

This is the class where I want to print the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Risk;

namespace printRisk
{
    public class Program
    {

        RiskService myRisk = new RiskService();

        public void Risks()
        {
            List<Risk> riskList = myRisk.GetRisks();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to enumerate and print the risk values on the Console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over the list with foreach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var risk in myRisk.GetRisks()) {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + risk.Id + ", Title: " + risk.Title); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also improvise on the solution provided by Glorfindel by overriding the ToString method in your Risk class as ...

```
public class Risk
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Resource Owner { get; set; }
    public RiskStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int RiskScore { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Risk Id: {0}, Risk Title: {1}, Owner Id: {2}, Owner Name: {3}, Risk Status: {4}, Risk score: {5}",
                                this.Id, this.Title, this.Owner.Id, this.Owner.Name, this.Status.ToString(), this.RiskScore);
    }
}
```

and now you can use the for loop to print these as follows

```
foreach (Risk risk in riskList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(risk.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(string combindedString = string.Join( ", ", myList.ToArray() ))
```

Should fix your problems, can see a few ways too improve your code structure too

Comment: Thank you, I know my code is a bit messy and I need to improve it, can you suggest some ways to improve it?

Comment: @Sulaco-Lv223 Yeah sure, for starters, put the list *riskList* into the class, not in its own method, that will generalise the list and help simplify it. Try searching through your code for methods (especially void methods) and compact them into a single method.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var r in riskList) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Id = {0} Name = {1}",r.Id, r.Name));
 }
```